# Netezza Regexp_replace Korean Character Breaks

Tags: netezza, regexp-replace

I ran this query in PDA(Netezza) to remove all special characters and unseen characters. In return, it shows the result below.

```
select regexp_replace('가나다라abcd0123','[^a-zA-Zㄱ-힝0-9]','')
```

It worked fine in Oracle but all Korean characters are broken when I ran in Netezza:

```
result
------------
????abcd0123
```

Does anybody know how to return Korean values without breaking any characters?

Comment: I have edited your question a little bit to make it more readable. Remember, on this site you are encouraged to [edit] and re-edit questions to improve them as much as possible; good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
select regexp_replace('가나다라abcd0123','[^a-zA-Zㄱ-힝0-9]','','u')
```